# Failure connecting local MySQL server

Tags: external-calls, sql, databases

I have locally installed and run the latest version of Oracle MySQL Community Server 8.0 on port 3306. I successfully established connections to it from locally installed Oracle MySQL Workbench 8.0 Community Edition ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO8bd.png)) and from DBeaver 21.2.

I wish to connect to it from *Mathematica* taking the advantage of the **External Language Input** and `RelationalDatabase` functionality.

Here is my attempt:

```
refMySQL = 
 DatabaseReference[{"Backend" -> "mysql", "Port" -> 3306, "Host" -> "localhost", 
   "Username" -> "admin", "Password" -> "admin", "Name" -> "sys"}];

DatabaseConnect@refMySQL
```

> [image: output]

The error description is: "Fatal Python error: _Py_HashRandomization_Init: failed to get random numbers to initialize Python".

Evaluating `RelationalDatabase@refMySQL` or `StartExternalSession@refMySQL` produces the same `Failure` message.

I also tried changing `"Backend"` to `"oracle"` and `"Username"` to `"root"` with the same result.

How to connect to the database?

I have installed and configured Python 3.9.7, which works well from *Mathematica*:

[image: screenshot]

(**Update**: after upgrading to *Mathematica* 13.1.0 the problem persists.)

Comment: If I look in the documentation it seems you should use an association instead of a list. Would that make a difference?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries It doesn't make a difference. With `DatabaseReference[<|"Backend"->"mysql","Port"->3306,"Host"->"localhost","Username"->"admin","Password"->"admin","Name"->"sys"|>]` I get the same error.

Comment: In the meanwhile, you could try connecting using the older [DatabaseLink](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/DatabaseLink/ref/OpenSQLConnection.html) which I understand uses Java instead of Python internally.

Comment: @GustavoDelfino I have trouble configuring ``"DatabaseLink`"``. Do you have a ready-made configuration for local MySQL 8.0?